# How to merge multiple files of the same format into a single file?

Tags: command-line, bash, merge

I have many files of the following format (all of them contain headers and have the same number of columns):

```
col1,col2,tt2,mm3
123,292810,1501223371-7504710,yes
1234,286130,1501223549-101722650,yes
334,276300,1501223650-71196600,yes
445,290100,1501224239-87923810,yes
```

The number of rows in each file is different, but it's always small (around 20-40 rows). All files are located in the same directory.

I want to merge all these multiple files into a single file without repeating headers. How can I do it using bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  use `awk` to concatenate the files, skipping the first line of each file unless it's the first line of all the files.

For example, if the files are named `part-00000` through `part-00199` then

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {next} {print}' part-{00000..00199}
```

Comment: The names of the files change between `part-00000` and `part-00199`. How to vary the number of `0` in the titles?

Comment: Globbing (with eg *) is ordered logically so `awk ... part-*` should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I'd grab the headers from one of the files and then grab everything from line 2 onwards from all the files.

```
head -1 part-00000 > output.csv
tail -n +2 part-* >> output.csv
```

Comment: I tested it. I get lines like `==> output.csv <==

==> part-00000 <==
` in `output.csv`. My files do not have any extension, therefore I substituted your second line of code by this one `tail -n +2 * >> output.csv`, but the result is incorrect as I explained.

Comment: I would guess that something else in the directory contains that. `part-*` is safer. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative to other solutions is using `cat`  and `grep` like:

```
cat * | grep -v '^col1,col2' > newfile
```

Comment: Should I list all column names manually?

Comment: isn't them same?